# Any good book suggestions for abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

could you suggest me an easy book on abstract algebra with solved problems and theory.

(or a pdf on the internet)

thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673342/good-books-on-abstract-algebra

Comment: Request for book suggestions are upvoted and my good questions are downvoted ,I don't know this site works like that

Comment: Wow, you know what, you are not the first person to look for recommendations of abstract algebra books! Next time please search first and experience the joy of kinship with the dozens of people who asked before and pioneered the way so that you didn't have to post another copy of what they did.

Comment: eemm ok sure, relax

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the book 'Contemporary Abstract Algebra' by Joseph A. Gallian

Link of the book: https://people.clas.ufl.edu/cmcyr/files/Abstract-Algebra-Text_Gallian-e8.pdf

Some hints and solutions of some of the exercises can be found here: https://www.slader.com/textbook/9781133599708-contemporary-abstract-algebra-8th-edition/